# Can we merge binary files without any copy operation by handling filesystem?

Tags: linux, shell, files, filesystems

I would like to merge efficiently binary files using a shell command and I quickly found classical ways like this one :

```
cat file1 file2 > file3
```

Not bad but :

1. It's slow. IO access are slow.
2. It needs extra space. I don't want to copy the files. Just concatenate them.

File systems are great to handle file fragmentation. Can't we just merge files using this mecanism?

Comment: Related: [A virtual file containing the concatenation of other files](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/94041)

Comment: Borderline duplicate of [Fastest way to concatenate files](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/118244)

Comment: I agree. And bordline duplicat with this one too : [link](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/80429/append-huge-files-to-each-other-without-copying-them). But this is not exactly the same. My challenge is "without any copy" by handling filesystem.

Comment: Loosely related:  [this answer by Gilles](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/365666/80216#365743).

Answer (score 11):

You can do this:

```
cat file2 file3 [...] filen >> file1
```

This will concatenate `file2`, `file3`,..., `filen` to the end of `file1` in-place. The `>>` operator tells the shell to write to the *end of the file*.

You want to leverage the file system to "handle file fragmentation". Unfortunately, there isn't any general way to do this. It's because "file systems" are much more general than file systems on disks — for example, you have [NFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_File_System), [FUSE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_in_Userspace), and many other mechanisms which let you expose any kind of resource (not just [block devices](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Device_file#Block_devices) such as hard disks) as a file system hierarchy. Even for block-device-based file systems, there isn't a standard mechanism to do this, and I don't know any implementation-specific ones either.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm investigating virtual file systems!

Comment: The only "easy" solution I have found to my challenge is a virtual file that encapsulate my files. I can't do an operation on my hard disk in the name abstraction. So I put even more abstraction to manage this ! :P Ironic isn't it ?

Comment: The first part of your answer is about copying files. I suggest to remove it and to keep only the last part related to manipulating the file system. It would then be my best answer!

Comment: that solution swaps bytes (little big endian) for me...

Answer (score 1):

Put your filenames in order in a text file called `list.txt` separated by new lines. Then run this in bash:

```
while read line; do echo -n . ; dd if="$line" of=out status=none conv=notrunc oflag=append; done < list.txt
```

This will create the concatenated file 'out' in the current directory.

Comment: Great script but there is a typo, instead of do, it should have been dd

while read line; do echo -n . ; dd if="$line" of=out status=none conv=notrunc oflag=append; done < list.txt

Comment: @BirdOfPrey Thank you I fixed it

Answer (score -1):

```
    dd if=firstfile.raw > completedfile.raw
    dd if=nfile.raw    >> completedfile.raw
    dd if=lastfile.raw >> completedfile.raw
```

Comment: Uhhh, ooooh, what an epic explanation...

Comment: This worked for me.