# How to gradually delete a file in parallel to encryption?

Tags: pipe, encryption, openssl, dm-crypt, ecryptfs

I need to encrypt a huge file but don't have sufficient storage on my hard-drive to store the file and its encrypted version at the same time.

It appears possible to gradually delete the file alongside the encryption so that the used space remains more or less the same.

If I encrypt my file with

```
 openssl aes-256-cbc  -in myfile -out myfile.aes-256-cbc
```

How would you suggest to gradually delete the original file `myfile` alongside the encryption?

Comment: what about `openssl aes-256-cbc  -in file  | pv -L <limit> > file` where `<limit>` is a `byte/s` limit set with `pv`

Comment: That would truncate `file` before starting to encrypt it...

Answer (score 1):

On Linux, you could use [`fallocate`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/fallocate.1.html) to "punch holes" in a file, i.e. throw out some of the data blocks. It requires an ext4, XFS or btrfs filesystem (or tmpfs).

```
$ perl -e 'print "a" x 16384' > foo
$ ls -sl foo
16 -rw-r--r-- 1 foo foo 16384 Oct 18 13:12 foo
$ fallocate -p -o0 -l 8192 foo
$ ls -sl foo
8 -rw-r--r-- 1 foo foo 16384 Oct 18 13:12 foo
```

Other systems may or may not have similar features, but I think the only portable system calls related to this are [`posix_fallocate`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/posix_fallocate.html) and [`truncate`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/truncate.html) which don't really help you since the first can only reserve new space for the file, and the second only allows truncating a file *from the end*.

In any case, you'd need to rig up a program to e.g. pipe the input file to `openssl` and discard the parts of the file that have already been read (but not the others). Not that hard to implement in any programming language, but not very safe either, since a crash would likely leave you with unusable pieces.

I don't know if any full-disk encryption utilities can encrypt a partition in-place.

Also, related: [Append huge files to each other without copying them](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/80429/170373)